# How to check value in a series with any?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, any

I'm working with Pandas. I need to create a new column in a dataframe according to conditions in other columns. I try to look for each value in a series if it contains a value (a condition to return text).This works when the values are exactly the same but not when the value is only a part of the value of the series.

```
if any("something") in df2["Symptom"]:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I got a yes, but any("something") also return a yes direcltly, it's always true without check in df2["Symptom"].

Also, .str.contains() doesn't work at all, i got the error :

```
Attribute error, attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I don't know why because df2["Symptom"] is a series.

Thanks for your help

## Edit : sample data : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srpjv/data/main/name.csv

The function :

df2["Deversement Service"] = df2.swifter.apply(conditions, axis=1)

The conditions without change :

def conditions(df2):

```
# Services 
if df2["Trigram MyPortal"] =="fr") is True return "Something"                                                                                       

# Autoconso                                                                                 
elif (df2["Trigram MyPortal"]=="Be")  is True: return "* Autoconso"                                                                                       
elif (df2["Trigram MyPortal"]=="De") is True: return "* Autoconso DE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df2['new'] = np.where(df2["Symptom"].str.contains('something'), 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost solved my problem, how do i return a True ? My whole line is : 

elif ((df2["Symptom"]=="things") | (df2["Symptom"]=="things2")) is True : return function()

I want to remove the "Is True" also

Comment: @SRP - In pandas is not possible use `if-else` like in this comments obviously. Is possible change data sample with sample function, sample data and expected ouput?

Comment: I understand it, but then i got the error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' with .str.contains. If i remove ".str", i got the error that series doesn't be used with contains

Comment: @SRP - yes, because cannot use it in loop.

Comment: Then, what can i do ?

Comment: @SRP - I need change question - sample data, expected ouut, sample function.

Comment: I edited it with a fraction of my dataframe and the condition